# How to assign a name to a branch in JCR

Tags: branch, jcr

JCR supports creating branches of a node. 
Is there an easy way to assign a name to a branch ?
Is there an easy way to get a certain branch, e.g. by name ?
Is there an easy way to access the latest version on a given branch ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the way how the version names are generated is hard coded in jackrabbit. But you can add labels for the versions using:

[VersionHistory.addVersionLabel()](http://www.day.com/maven/jsr170/javadocs/jcr-1.0/javax/jcr/version/VersionHistory.html#addVersionLabel%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean%29)

and then later retrieve it using:

[VersionHistory.getVersionByLabel()](http://www.day.com/maven/jsr170/javadocs/jcr-1.0/javax/jcr/version/VersionHistory.html#getVersionByLabel%28java.lang.String%29)

the latest version of a branch would then be the version without a successor. you would need to loop over the versions until you find it.